# SQL get all joined elements, specify join entity via joined table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get all related rows to a single entity, by specifying the entity via one of the related rows.

```
CREATE TABLE entity (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
)

CREATE TABLE related (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
    key VARCHAR(32) UNIQUE NOT NULL
    entity_id INTEGER FOREIGN KEY (`entity.id`)
)
```

I want all of the `related` rows for a specific `entity` but I am not sure how to do the join, I always get only the related with the key I am using to dereference.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    entity e,
    related r
         JOIN
    related r1
 WHERE
     e.id = r.entity_id
         AND r.key= 'lookup key'
         AND r1.entity_id = e.id;
```

So if I execute

```
INSERT INTO entity VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO related VALUES (1, 'lookup key' 1),
    (2, 'other key' 1), 
    (3, 'another key' 1), 
    (4, 'this key' 2), 
    (5, 'that key' 2), 
    (6, 'their key' 2);
```

I want

```
entity.id    related.id    related.key    related.entity_id
1            1             lookup key     1
1            2             other key      1
1            3             another key    1
```

But I always get

```
entity.id    related.id    related.key    related.entity_id
1            1             lookup key     1
```

and I don't want this

```
entity.id    related.id    related.key    related.entity_id
1            1             lookup key     1
1            2             other key      1
1            3             another key    1
2            4             this key       2
2            5             that key       2
2            6             their key      2
```

I know the SQL isnt 100% correct.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I made changes to make the question more complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logically what you really want to do is constrain the entity by id, so there's a few different ways to do this, but I think the syntax and idea behind a [correlated subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/correlated-subqueries.html) is one of the clearest.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    entity e,
    JOIN
    related r
 WHERE
     r.entity_id = e.entity_id
     AND e.entity_id IN (SELECT entity_id FROM related WHERE key = 'lookup key')
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I am trying to avoid using subqueries for performance reasons. Could you add one of the other techniques to the answer?

Comment: When properly indexed there is no performance penalty for this query.  You should use explain extended format = json to determine this type of thing, as well as timings, rather than assuming that you understand what the database is going to do and how performant that is going to be.  Assumed indexes on key, as well as the foreign keys of course.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you filtering on `key`, if you want all `key` values?  Then, from what you say, you seem to want a simple `JOIN`:

```
SELECT e.*, r.*
FROM entity e JOIN
     related r
     ON e.id = r.entity_id;
```

Comment: I am filtering on key because I don't want all `entity` rows I only want the entity row to which that `key` belongs, along with all of the other `related` rows belonging to that `entity`